# Bring back max version

Tags: sql, max

I have the following SQL statement,

```
SELECT NAME,TEXT, VERSION
FROM VTABLE 
WHERE  VERSION <= (select version from BTABLE where ID = 'TEST')
```

Brings back -

```
Name  Text    Version     
----|-------|--------|
A   | APP1  | 1 |
A2  | APP1  | 2 |
B   | APP2  | 1 |
C   | APP3  | 1 |
```

However I need the max version returned of each app only so the result should look like -

```
Name  Text    Version     
----|-------|--------|
A2  | APP1  | 2 |
B   | APP2  | 1 |
C   | APP3  | 1 |
```

I have have tied to JOIN on both the VTABLE version and the BTABLE version like this -

```
SELECT V.NAME, V.TEXT, MAX(V.VERSION)
FROM VTABLE V
WHERE  V.VERSION <= JOIN(select B.version from BTABLE B where B.ID = 'TEST') ON V.VERSION = B.version
```

However this is failing. Its pretty much a case of, based on the B.version, I need the APPs returned for this (with the max V.VERSION)

Comment: Please add DBMS in your tag list

Comment: your BTABLE and VTABLE how are related?

Comment: @Joe Taras related by VERSION

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way ... use row_number ... If you using T-SQL ... my temp table represent data that are returned by your query ... you can just nest that query instead of `from #Version`

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Version') is not null drop table #Version
create table #Version (name nvarchar(10), [Text] nvarchar(10), [Version] int)

insert into #Version (Name, [Text], [Version])
values 
('A', 'APP1', 1),
('A2', 'APP1', 2),
('B', 'APP2', 1),
('C', 'APP3', 1)

select name, Text, Version from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by [Text] order by [Version] desc) as RowNum
    from #Version) src
where RowNum = 1
```